# Why was this question "returned" to another SE site?

Tags: discussion, closing, close-reasons, migration

This is a question about [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3835112/81360). The post was originally from the [Mathematica SE site](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/230509/8447) and was migrated to MSE (*math* SE) because the underlying question is one of mathematics rather than one of programming. The question was then closed due to lack of context, which makes sense (but in my opinion was unwarranted since some context was provided by the asker in the comments).

What doesn't make sense to me is that the question was migrated *back* to the Mathematica SE site, which seems to me to be a poor decision since it is indeed a question about math. So, two questions:

1. Why was this second migration done? (Is this an automatic consequence of the question being closed on the second site?)
2. Can the post be migrated back to MSE? Should it be migrated back?

Of course, none of this matters all that much; the asker has an answer after all. Nevertheless, it seems weird so I thought this question was worth asking.

Comment: If a migrated question gets closed for a reason other than being a duplicate, that rejects the migration. It's automatic.

Comment: @DanielFischer I thought that might be the case; thanks for confirming

Comment: The guiding principle is "Don't migrate crap". That is to say, things that will get closed on the target site, and not worth the trouble.

Comment: @Asaf Interesting. In that case it would seem to me that the moderators of one SE site are serving as the gatekeepers for another, which doesn't strike me as the correct way to do things

Comment: Note that no moderators were involved on *this* side of the question, nor they *had* to get involved on the other side of the question. The point is that SE as a network should strive for good content, and bad content should be closed and delete, not migrated.

Comment: @Asaf That's a fair point. Thanks for the insight into the process

Comment: @AsafKaragila Unfortunately users from other site usually do not know the standard here.

Comment: [Related post on migration in meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: "Can the post be migrated back to MSE? Should it be migrated back?"  If you feel there is a good/interesting math question involved, then you can simply post here, with a link to the closed question on Mathematica.SE for historical context.  Please present such a new Question in the best way possible for Math.SE guidelines.